# Помогите ответить на несколько вопросов по коду C++

Tags: c++, указатели, типы-данных

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему функция `Display` (10 строка) имеет тип `string`, а не `void`? Ведь можно же использовать `void` и выводить `cout`-ом, вместо `return`-а. В общем, объясните почему `string`-ом предпочтительнее или наоборот. И какие могут возникнуть проблемы в дальнейшим, используя тот или иной вариант. И ещё вопрос. Почему используется указатель в `CFunction* Diff()` (12 строка) и для чего нужно `return nullptr;`. Спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class CFunction
{
public:
    virtual string Display() = 0;
    virtual double Calc(double x) = 0;
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return nullptr; }
};

class CUnares : public CFunction
{
public:
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return nullptr; }

protected:
    CFunction *arg;
};

class CBinares : public CFunction
{
public:
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return nullptr; }

protected:
    CFunction *left;
    CFunction *right;
};

class CPlus : public CBinares
{
public:
    virtual double Calc(double x) { return left -> Calc(x) + right -> Calc(x); }
    virtual string Display() { return left -> Display() + " + " + right -> Display(); }
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return new CPlus(left -> Diff(), right -> Diff()); }

    CPlus()
    {
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    CPlus(CFunction *l, CFunction *r)
    {
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};

class CMinus : public CBinares
{
public:
    virtual double  Calc(double x) { return left -> Calc(x) - right -> Calc(x); }
    virtual string Display() { return left -> Display() + " - " + right -> Display(); }
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return new CMinus(left -> Diff(), right -> Diff()); }

    CMinus()
    {
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    CMinus(CFunction *l, CFunction *r)
    {
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};

class CUmn : public CBinares
{
public:
    virtual double  Calc(double x) { return left -> Calc(x) * right -> Calc(x); }
    virtual string Display() { return "(" + left -> Display() + ") * (" + right -> Display() + ")"; }
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return new CPlus(new CUmn(left -> Diff(), right), new CUmn(left, right -> Diff())); }

    CUmn()
    {
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    CUmn(CFunction *l, CFunction *r)
    {
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};

class CDel : public CBinares
{
public:
    virtual double  Calc(double x) { return left -> Calc(x) / right -> Calc(x); }
    virtual string Display(){ return "(" + left -> Display() + ") / (" + right -> Display() + ")"; };
    virtual CFunction* Diff(){ return new CDel(new CMinus(new CUmn(left -> Diff(), right), new CUmn(left, right -> Diff())), new CUmn(right, right)); }

    CDel()
    {
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    CDel(CFunction *l, CFunction *r)
    {
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};

class CExp : public CUnares
{
public:
    virtual double  Calc(double x) { return exp(arg -> Calc(x)); }
    virtual string Display() { return "exp(" + arg -> Display() + ")"; }
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return new CUmn(new CExp(arg), arg -> Diff()); }

    CExp() { arg = nullptr; }
    CExp(CFunction *a) { arg = a; }
};

class CConst : public CFunction
{
public:
    double Value;
    virtual double Calc(double x) { return Value; }
    virtual string Display() { return std::to_string(Value); }
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return new CConst(0); }

    CConst(double v) { Value = v; };
};

class CX : public CFunction
{
public:
    virtual double Calc(double x) { return x; }
    virtual string Display() { return "x"; }
    virtual CFunction* Diff() { return new CConst(1); }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CFunction *y1 = new CConst(5);
    cout << y1 -> Display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это небольшая такая масштабируемость. Этот метод вернет некоторое значение, а что с ним делать уже решать пользователю метода: выводить в консоль, писать в файл или по сети посылать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ведь можно же использовать void и выводить cout-ом, вместо return-а

Принцип разделения обязанностей. Класс не должен заниматься несвойственным ему делом. Код получается более универсальным. Вы можете использовать результат функции `Display` по-разному.

К тому же, здесь используется рекурсия. И хотя в данном случае вполне можно заменить возврат значение на `std::cout`, потому что вывод все равно идет слева направо, но если вам захочется комбинировать строки как-то иначе, то у вас ничего не выйдет.

> Почему используется указатель в CFunction* Diff()

Потому что нужно вернуть полиморфный тип - наследник CFunction. Возвращать по значению полиморфный тип нельзя.

> для чего нужно return nullptr

nullptr - нулевой указатель. Это значит, что по-умолчанию у функции дифференциал не определен.

Comment: >Потому что там используется рекурсия для формирования итоговой строки


безотносительно использования рекурсии не очень хорошо говнокодить, намертво связывая класс, моделирующий математические абстракции и систему ввода/вывода

Answer (score 0):

- Почему функция `Display()` возвращает строку, а не выводит ее? Потому, что так задумано автором кода. Это функция, согласно нынешнему замыслу автора, и не должна ничего никуда выводить. Назначение это функции - просто генерировать *строковое* представление математического [под]выражения. А уж куда эту строку направит вызывающий код - на экран, в файл, в еще большую строку или еще куда - это дело вызывающего кода.

  Понятно, что название `Display()` не очень подходит для такой функции. Ее лучше было бы назвать `ToString()` или еще как-то в этом роде.

  (Вполне может быть, что изначально функция `Display()` выводила результат прямо в `cout` и возвращала `void`. Но потом автор кода понял ограниченность такого подхода и поменял функциональность. А название `Display()` осталось.)
- Функция `Diff()` стоит [под]дерево математического выражения с корнем в данном узле и возвращает указатель на этот корневой узел.

  `return nullptr` делается в тех классах, которые не формируют никакого узла в дереве. На самом деле, если посмотреть внимательно, никакого `return nullptr` делать не надо было бы - в таких классах можно было просто оставить функцию `Diff()` чистой (pure virtual).